# Faster way to rate media files in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

From what I understand, I need to go in the properties of the file, then the "detail" tab and set the rating there. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rate them in bulk in Windows Media Player (a bit different than this on Windows 7, but fairly similar):

- In the menu select **File -> Add to Media Library** and choose what you want to add (probably a whole folder of media)

  [image]
- Let it add all your files

  [image]
- Navigate to the **Media Library** to see the media you've added and select what you want to rate from the imported media (All Music, All Video, etc)

  [image]
- You can then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> (sequence) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> (1 at a time) the files you want to rate. Then right click and go to **Rate Selected Items** and choose your desired rating.

  [image]

Comment: I assume that for images, I should use Windows Photo Gallery?

Comment: Yep, the same highlight and rate method can be applied there!